# Como validar si existe un comodín con expresión regular y reemplazar con otro texto si existe, sino dejar vacio

Tags: regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, expresion

estoy creando uris en codeigniter 3, pero como el sitio web debo pasarlo a más de 800 idiomas necesito reducir la cantidad de líneas usadas rehusando líneas de códigos con expresiones regulares.

ejemplo: esta ruta lleva a ese controlador, tenga amp o no la url

```
$route['en/(amp\/)?the-bible']= "$1biblia_enlinea";
```

Coincide con estas dos url:

*http://localhost/en/the-bible   ->  biblia_enlinea

*http://localhost/en/amp/the-bible   ->  amp/biblia_enlinea

Pero tengo una tercera opción que es la que no se como resolver de uri

```
$route['en/(amp\/)?the-bible(\/version\/)?(.*)?']= "$1biblia_enlinea$2$3";
```

coincide con esta url:
*http://localhost/en/the-bible/version/king-james-version

Necesito que si existe el comodín $2 que es la palabra "version" en la url. Entonces me coloque esta frase "detalle_version" cuando llamo el comodín y si no existe el comodín entonces lo deje en blanco.

Si esta fuera la url
http://localhost/amp/en/the-bible/version/king-james-version

La expresión haga esto:

$route['en/(amp/)?the-bible(/version/)?(.*)?']= "amp/biblia_enlinea/detalle_version/king-james-version";

Pero si el uri es este:

http://localhost/en/the-bible

La expresión solo haga esto:

$route['en/(amp/)?the-bible(/version/)?(.*)?']= "biblia_enlinea";

En pocas palabras, necesito saber como verificar si el comodín existe y si existe coloque la  palabra "detalle_version", si no existe deje vacío.